# aws xray sampling not working on http status code

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-xray

How can we sample the data in aws xray on the basis of http status code, e.g I would to sample 40% of records with status code 200 and 100% of records with status code 500. Below is the sample json but I cannot sample the data

```
const rules = {
    "rules": [{
        "description": "get users",
        "service_name": "*",
        "http_method": "GET",
        "url_path": "*",
        "fixed_target": 0,
        "rate": 0.25
        "attributes": {
            "status": 200
         }
    }],
    "default": { "fixed_target": 1, "rate": 0.1},
    "version": 1
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature you require is currently not supported by the X-Ray SDK.
AWS mentions this in the docs [1]:

> - (optional) Attributes (key and value) – Segment attributes that are known when the sampling decision is made.
>
>   - X-Ray SDK – **Not supported**. The SDK ignores rules that specify attributes.
>   - Amazon API Gateway – Headers from the original HTTP request.

You can also see that it is not supported when looking at the source code of the sampling rule in the AWS X-Ray SDK for Node.js. [2]

I think that you can only specify the *Attributes* property from the AWS Management Console (not the SDK) and only for the Amazon API Gateway.

#### Solutions

1. Increase the sample count to 100% (not recommended because it effectively destroys the purpose of sampling - although maybe feasible for a small portion of HTTP endpoints).
2. Use an API Gateway (possibly costly).
3. Open an Issue on GitHub with a feature request (FR) and write to the AWS support to submit a FR if you are on a support plan (not very promising according to my experience with AWS X-Ray development speed).

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-sampling.html#xray-console-sampling-options
[2] https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/blob/6bade5ad006a47f19a5352a40f1ad2823f404e63/packages/core/lib/middleware/sampling/sampling_rule.js